# Connecting SignalR + AspNetCore API with nginx proxy from Xamarin Forms project always returning connection timeout

Tags: c#, nginx, xamarin, centos, signalr

I'm having connection timed out error when connecting to signalr hub written in c# aspnetcore, hosted on centos with nginx reverse proxy. Client app is a Xamarin Forms project. It works fine when tested with a device and emulator and the api running on a windows pc. Details as below. Have tried almost almost anything I could find online for the past 2 days but still no luck.

**ASPNETCORE API project, SignalR in startup.cs**

in ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddSignalR();
```

in Configure

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapHub<LocationHub>("/api/locationhub");
        });
```

**nginx config**

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:7900;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering    off;
}

location /api/locationhub {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:7900;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

**Error**

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  Message=Connection timed out
  Source=mscorlib
```

Details show that it was caused by connection start async line:

```
if (hubConnection.State == HubConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            }
```

Any help, direction would be really appreciated. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you been able to connect to your Signal R service from another source? (browser, other client). You need to prove the signalling service is working before debugging the issue in Xamarin. The errors on the clientside can be a little unhelpful sometimes so i'd suggest ensuring the API is working correctly first.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Follow your suggestion and wrote a console app to connect to hub. Turns out it was a firewall issue that I missed to enable on cent os. And now console app can successfully connect to hub and send/receive messages. However occasionally I'm receiving this: 
System.IO.IOException: 'The server disconnected before the handshake could be started.' Guess it's my connectivity issue. Will try again with my xamarin project and I hope it will work. Thanks again.

Comment: What configuration did you add to your firewall to enable signalr on CentOS?